# Compound condition inside case clause

Tags: sql, oracle, conditional-statements

Howcome I write, for a given example,

```
select attendee, begindate
case evaluation
    when 1 then 'bad'
    when 2 then 'mediocre'
    when 3 then 'ok'
    when 4 then 'good'
    when 5 then 'excellent'
    else 'not filled in'
end
from registrations
where course = 'S02'
```

compound condition like `when 1` [and] *something else* 'then' value.

What operator should use instead of [and]?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Suggest you construct your case slighly differently:

```
case
    when evaluation in (1,2) then 'bad'
    when evaluation = 3 then 'ok'
    when evaluation = 4 then 'good'
    when evaluation = 5 then 'excellent'
    else 'not filled in'
end
```

Comment: Thanks! In addition I've found a good article http://www.oracle-developer.net/display.php?id=206